# I run react native app in linux with android studio. But i always got builds tools 27.0.3 correpted

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I install native command using react-native init and install latest android studio 3.3 v. But when i run app it always run on platform from of 27.0.3 which shows error or corrupted. Help me to debug it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Could you please paste the actual output instead of just an image?  Seeing your source code that caused the error will also be a big help.  Please refer to this document for how to ask a good question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I use ubuntu 16.04. In install android studio and react native app wit react-native init. After I run the app it show this error. I google alot but i didn't found any solution. Please can you help

Comment: Please post the actual output and not a screen shot.